# ReplacementSpan in multiautocomplete textview overlap

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, autocompletetextview, spannablestring

Hi i have multiple autocomplete text view with space tokenizer and use ReplacementSpan for background color change in each contacts

my custom replacement code is

```
public class MyForgroudSpan : ReplacementSpan
{
    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas, ICharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint)
    {

        var rect = new RectF(x , top, x + paint.MeasureText(text, start, end)+8, bottom);
        paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#E5E5E6");
        canvas.DrawRect(rect, paint);
        paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Black;
        int xPos = Java.Lang.Math.Round(x + (8 / 2));
        int yPos = (int)((canvas.Height / 2) - ((paint.Descent() + paint.Ascent()) / 2));

        canvas.DrawText(text, start, end, xPos, yPos, paint);

    }
    public override int GetSize(Paint paint, ICharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm)
    {
        return Java.Lang.Math.Round(paint.MeasureText(text, start, end))+8;
    }
}
```

i set spannable string here

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(Text.trim());
ssb.SetSpan(new MyForgroudSpan(), x, x + c.Length, SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
```

its ok when multiple auto complete textview have single line but it come to multiple line means it overlap each text

please see the screens

1.single line

[image: single line image]

2.multiline image

[image: Multiline image]

When i use y value like this

```
canvas.DrawText(text, start, end, xPos, y, paint);
```

[image: lyout like this no vertical space between line]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your ReplacementSpan only to change the background color you could as well simply use a BackgroundColorSpan:

```java
ssb.SetSpan(
  new BackgroundColorSpan(
    Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#E5E5E6"), 
    x,
    x + c.Length, 
    SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive));
```

The overlap problem occurs because you are not using the y value in your DrawText Method. If you replace it with

```
canvas.DrawText(text, start, end, xPos, y, paint);
```

it should look proper

Comment: yep. as mentioned, if you want to stick with your ReplacementSpan just factor in the y parameter of the Draw method in your canvas.DrawText. In your snippet you are ignoring it completely. This results in the text being drawn at the same y-offset, regardless of its line number.

Comment: please check my updated question when i use y value are background span text look like this even i set extra line space

Comment: so the overlapping is gone - i assume you want the lines to have a small linepitch?

Comment: How can i do sir, can you please help me. I spend more than 2 days for this

Comment: Substract an offset when drawing your background. Example: var rect = new RectF(x , top, x + paint.MeasureText(text, start, end)+8, bottom - 2); results in a 2px gap at the bottom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80269/discussion-between-manikandan-and-mdi1984).

Comment: its worked fine but if i need extend space between line what shall i do, because when i do bottom-5 or more bottom text is not covered with background

Comment: you have to increase the android:lineSpacingExtra="..px" in your TextView to compensate this

Comment: there is no luck, i m going to move image span but its reduce the text size and not readable