# TextView Span with custom content

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to create Span that can modify content. So, for example i need to draw text without first 3 and last 4 characters. I'm trying to use Replacable span:

```
class ItalicReplacement extends ReplacementSpan {

@Override
public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
    paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
    return (int) paint.measureText(text, start + 3, end - 4);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
    paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);

    canvas.drawText(text, start + 3, end - 4, x, y, paint);
}
}
```

But replacable span draws as an image. Not as text. So, i can't work with it as a regular text. And the main problem is wrapping (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXJUj.png).

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350232/how-can-i-make-my-custom-replacementspan-wrap) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747417/replacementspan-in-multiautocomplete-textview-overlap). There is the same problems.

So, it there any other way to do what i want? For example, i want to do clickable spoilers or urls that displays only domain. May other *Span can do that?

Comment: no,  you have to use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html#replace(int, int, java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: I know. It's reserve way x) Ok, for urls i can make list with full urls and replace it in TextView. But what about spoilers?

Comment: about spoilers?  what do you mean?

Comment: text with foreground fill that hides on click

Comment: see http://codeshare.io/R67nE

Comment: Ok, from your class that inherits ClickableSpan i can access widget that includes span (but only when onlick called). So, can i access widget from class that inherits MetricAffectingSpan or CharacterStyle? For my structure it's the best way.

Comment: so pass it via the ctor

Comment: see above codeshare.io link again